# Compress Random 32-bit Integers: How close can we get to Shannon Entropy?

Tags: algorithm, integer, compression

I've developed a lossless compression algorithm that *compresses* 32-bit integers (of unknown frequency/probability) to 31.95824 bits per integer (it works a lot better for smaller values, just as most compression algorithms do).  Obviously it isn't possible to compress uniformly-distributed random data to become smaller than its uncompressed size.

Therefore my question is, which lossless compression algorithms get closest to the Shannon Entropy of 32 bits per integer for pseudorandom data, assuming 32-bit integers?

Essentially, I'm looking for a table which includes compression algorithms and their respective bits-per-integer value for positive, compressed, 32-bit integers.

Comment: I guess those that monitor input-to-output-size ratio and emit a itty-bitty "literal block" tag followed by exactly that.

Comment: Have you tried any standard algorithms yourself?  Are you working in a language where implementations are readily available?

Comment: P.S. There's really no difference between random 32-bit integers and random 8-bit ones.

Comment: @MarkRansom I'm just curious to see how my algorithm performs against others'.  I've been testing other algorithms myself, but I imagined someone had asked a similar question before and possibly had some information that would be useful.  Also, 8-bit integers don't work well with my algorithm unfortunately due to there being such a small set of values.

Comment: My point is that you can create a random 32-bit value by concatenating 4 8-bit values. Standard algorithms will operate on 8-bit values.

Comment: `[compressed bits-per-positive 32-bit integer` essentially, 31 uniformly random bits, which makes 32.8958 less close.

Comment: If you can compress a uniform distribution of 32-bit integers to 31.96 bits each on average, then you have done something mathematically impossible. Which means that you cannot complete the decompression losslessly in all cases.

Comment: @MarkAdler I’ve done it, but re-running the algorithm won’t compress it any further for the most part.  It takes advantage of the leading 0 in positive two’s complement integers.

Answer (score 1):

When you say "it works a lot better for smaller values", I presume that you have a transformation from the 32-bit integer to a variable-bit-length representation that is optimized for some non-uniform expected distribution of values. Then that same transformation applied to a *uniform* distribution of 32-bit values will necessarily take more than 32 bits on average. How much more depends on how non-uniform a distribution you started with.

So the answer is, of course you can get to 32 bits exactly by doing nothing at all to the number. But then you are not optimized for the application implied by the non-uniform distribution you designed to.

Comment: You're mostly correct; the expected distribution of values is still uniform, but only performs well when the range doesn't encompass all possible positive 32-bit integers.  What I'm trying to ask is: when existing compression algorithms attempt to compress random 32-bit integers, how close do they come to 32 bits?  Essentially I'm looking for a table which includes compression algorithms and their respective bits-per-integer value.

Comment: The obvious limiting case is that you can prepend your sequence with one bit that is 0 if the subsequent data is not compressed, and 1 if it is. Then the  expansion of incompressible data is one bit.

Answer (score 0):

The identity function requires precisely 32 bits per 32 bit integer, which is pretty hard to beat. (There are many other length-preserving bijections, if you insist on changing the data stream.)

It's not obvious to me what other criteria you might be employing to recommend an algorithm which does worse than that. Perhaps you believe that the input stream is not truly a uniform sample; rather, it is a restricted to (or significantly biased towards) a subset of the universe, but you do not a priori know what the subset is. In that case, the entropy of the stream is less than one (if there is an upper bound on the size of the subset which is reasonably less than the size of the universe) and you might be able to actually compress the input stream.

It's worth noting that unless messages are fixed-length, the length of the message needs to be taken into account in the computation of entropy, both in the numerator and the denominator. For very long messages, that can mostly be ignored but if messages are short, the cost of message delimiters (or explicit length indicators) can be significant. (Otherwise, "compressing" to 103% of original size is a somewhat humptydumptyesque definition of "to compress".)

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what pcodec (https://github.com/mwlon/pcodec) was built to do: lossless compression of numbers drawn from a numerical distribution. I'm not aware of any other algorithms that do this. You can see its results on real-world datasets in the readme. The exact compression ratio you can achieve is of course highly dependent on your data.